# How to make typed chat messages display on the screen? (socket.io and node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on creating a chat app using socket.io and node.js,
the server is connected, and both socket.io and client-side socket.io are connected,
yet when I type something on the localhost page and press enter, it doesn't show anything on the page. How to make my chat appear on the page? Thank you in advance.

<index.js>

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('message:' + msg);
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

<script.js>

```
var socket = io();

var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value) {
        socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
        input.value = '';
    }
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

<index.html>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Chat App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off">
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your event listener try adding else and console.log something and check your console or try adding any error you get in your question

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so could you show me how to do it using the code?

Comment: check your console first and edit your question  i need to know the error maaybe yes

Comment: so I checked the console with console log and it shows what I wrote :(

Comment: in else condition?

Answer (score 0):

**In your index.html try this**

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

Becouse your listener listen for submit event